# Series RLC circuit - Phase difference between voltages across inductor and resistor is not exactly 180, why?

Tags: ac, inductor, phasor

In phasor analysis we put *inductor voltage* along positive \$j\$ axis and *capacitor voltage* along negative \$j\$.
So these two voltages are exactly \$180\$ degrees apart.

But in simulation below, the two voltages are not meeting on \$t\$ axis. Why?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOYakX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: They look 180 degrees out of phase to me, just with a DC offset.

Comment: Oh right! Looks capacitor has some transient voltage at t=0...

Comment: Your title is in error.

Comment: @Andyaka I see now...  got mixed up DC offset with phase. I should have more faith in math haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vc has a DC offset , otherwise it appears to be  in sync with resonance after 10T for T=RC=100us, it should be discharged from any initial condition within reason.

I never use Circuit Lab.

However the initial voltage on Vc is create by sin 0 deg and not an initial Vdc condition.  Starting with sin 90 deg will result in 0 V offset.

### trivia

Remember this fact of initial conditions for sin voltage thru an LC circuit

When current is interrupted, in order to prevent the initial condition of remanence and possible saturation of the core with a very loud core hum, companies like ABB make smart reclosure power switches to reclose the grid at the same voltage phase as when it was interrupted .  The transformer current will decay L/R=T but not after experiencing huge winding stresses on the order of tons from transient core saturation.

[image] [image]

Note the two simulations for initial voltage phase of 0 then 90 deg, how it creates initial voltages for L and C differently and Vc starts with a Vp DC offset voltage with Sin 0.

[My Falstad Simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCCsCmC0CMF4DYB08DMiAcyN7GwCZsBOEZJSKDKOeeAKAHMQN8QiB2ItjjMABZw4RgCc%20yEIOySQ8EiMRhGAJTkzO2WZqSdIYQxDCpqx8KcYBjOd17sp8Ur2Oojh%20CFgnDkQaXwiSiIwBS5IDGEVAHc5J15BQ3lnTkYAGzjFB2SXC3dQvLABUmwuIpJIZGRBQWQXRljshR0k5tTE2kEUeSk-YWxzIgB9aqGwIcSSsdQ6yGn3Ui5kSqI5hCHh4YxGDulu0l6anvN4EcExibApk1np0-WmXa7HJagjokSROdHxhSJScY%20MBcbARUiCSAfAFBYinIGhIYPHZFPZSVaHYQYEIiDBnC6TbDzK5LFZzEz3U5MIA). Right clock source to change phase then press reset and stop whenever.

I just noticed my error in placing the Cap from bottom to top so my voltage was displayed inverted.  So I selected Cap, the "swap ends" and replotted

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I just simulated again. After ~1s, the average voltage on capacitor is indeed going to 0. Then circuitlab must be assuming some initial voltage on capacitor at t=0. Wish there is some way to set initial conditions in circuitlab...

Comment: Like Falstad's , there must be an option

Comment: @across There's no "ghostly" initial voltage, they're zero but what you see is the effect of a normal RLC transient response. You just have to wait long enough for these to decay. Even 1 ms is enough.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen haha ok you mean at t=0, the voltage on capacitor is 0, but the capacitor starts charging up in positive direction(sin(wt) input). So there is asymmetry initially and this decays over time.  Is my understanding accurate?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen  You misunderstand. with Sin 0 there is a DC offset after a half cycle.  Please correct your error.  My error is the cap was placed inverted so the voltage across the cap is inverted

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen  has lost his mind thinking I said there was a 'ghostly' initial voltage. It is integrated after 1/2 cycle. I initially simply said it was not at steady state.

Comment: Ohkk.. cos(wt) will not give a dc offset.  Lesson learned: phasor analysis and LTI stuff is only good for obtaining steady state response. For transient we must use differential equations. Haven't started laplace transforms yet but I'm happy for now I know how to work small circuits with differential equations xD transient voltage on capacitor is given by $$v_c(t) = c_1e^{-p+j\omega t}+c_2e^{-p-j\omega t}$$

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75  lol you're funny :D I'm pretty sure that "ghostly" comment was directed toward me, not you. Because I literally thought circuitlab was putting some initial voltage on capacitor before posting this question...

Comment: yup . . . . . . . .

Comment: storage charge and remanence phase matters for high power equipment during high current disconnect

Comment: you mean to save the receiving  transformer from \$Ldi/dt\$ stress during disconnection in power generation plants and distribution stations.. a little beyond my head... but  it makes sense. so during disconnection, they drive the grid with an identical  voltage with same phase.. using some auxiliary supply perhaps...

Comment: The remanence charge in large power transformers has a long enough time constant that if you don't power up in the  same phase as your left off, it can damage windings from huge current forces if the core saturates from voltage and not load current.  When cores saturated L goes towards 0 and all that is left is DCR. Otherwise in order to quench the grid energy at the zero-crossing during a breaker fault condition is quenching a possible large energy arc. So > 100 MVA transformers can be quite expensive built like a tank.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Please don't make me regret the +1 I gave and read my comment again, it's directed at OP (see the `@across` in front).

Comment: @across The voltage across the capacitor, unless special simulations are imposed, will start from zero and cause an initial raised cosine (since it's integrating), and that causes a DC which will decay, normally, since there is no DC average in a sine. If it didn't behave like that I would worry.

Comment: Understood.. this exercise cleared up a lot of confusion on decaying transient and final steadystate. Thanks again you both are awesome :)

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen  Forgiven,  But yes it is the integration of  RC  current not  "raised cosine" response that does it.   It is well overdamped integration.  Remove L and see if I am right

Comment: Tony, you were the one who misinterpreted my comment and who said I lost my mind, so you can't be the one who forgives, I can. And I do, because mistakes can happen. Nothing in my replies was aimed at you, and the fact that I upvoted should tell you that I agreed with you, one way or another. You seem tensed, do you live in Ukraine, or nearby? At any rate, there's no need to dwell on this since the answer has been selected; the client should be satisfied.